# WinRT Gesture Support

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, gesture

Are there built in APIs for handling Gestures in WinRT (pinch to zoom specifically). I already have zoom working with the mouse, using:

```
  public event PointerEventHandler PointerWheelChanged; // UIElement class
```

and I need the equivalent with touch. Any pointers on the best way to accomplish this? Should I use one of these 'manipulation' events?

```
  public event ManipulationDeltaEventHandler ManipulationDelta;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-186T) talk by Reed Townsend discusses how to use gesture recognition APIs.  You can also look at the [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx) class for more details on how to do gesture recognition in Windows Runtime apps.